# реализация не совсем fab кнопки

Tags: android, listview, button

не могу реализовать круглую кнопку как на картинке [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

HEADER1 всегда сверху, HEADER2  скролится в месте с LISTVIEW.
Если можно, хотелось бы реализовать без сторонних библиотек FAB кнопок.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

[`FloatingActionButton`](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html) входит в стандартную библиотеку поддержки Google - `support:design`.

Так как по сути это виджет в отдельном `FrameLayout`, что значит, что он располагается в отдельном слое и спозиционировать его вы можете в любом месте родительского контейнера по правилам, применимым к, собственно, `FrameLayout`.
Например, верхний правый угол экрана с отступами по `20dp` от краев экрана:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<-- другие элементы разметки -->

  <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|top"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Естественно, что маржины вы можете указать и отдельно для каждой из сторон при необходимости.
В данном случае кнопка будет всегда находится в своей позиции, как бы не изменялись позиции других `View`.

Кроме того, возможно "привязать" FAB к какому то `View` на разметке по его `id` и спозиционировать кнопку относительно этого `View` с помощью атрибутов `layout_anchor` и `layout_anchorGravity`.
Например, справа внизу контейнера `ViewA`, с частичным выходом (в данном случае 50%) на "территорию" контейнера `ViewB`:

```
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewA"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewB"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/viewA"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

В данном случае кнопка будет перемещаться вместе с контейнером,к которому прикреплена, если он будет перемещаться по экрану.

На этом возможности размещения FAB на разметке исчерпываются.

Comment: еще один вопрос, где можно скачать support библиотеки обычным .jar файлом, так как в силу некоторых обстоятельств пользоваться sdk manager не получается.

Comment: Вам и не нужен для этого SDK Manager, вы должны добавить зависимость в build.gradle